# Waiting for Polymer to load

Tags: polymer, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on getting some acceptance tests to work with Capybara.  The main parts of the application leverage Polymer.  There are some key parts of the application that require the test to wait for the Polymer library and the application code to load.  Is there a Polymer centric way to wait for Polymer and the application to load.  I currently am using sleep statements, but this is really bloating the test run times.

Comment: It would be better if you provide more details, like OS, ruby version, devkit version, code etc..

Comment: I'm running on a brand new Mac (El Capitan), Ruby 2.1.5p273, etc.  I'm also running the latest version of Polymer JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that polymers FOUC prevention uses an 'unresolved' attribute on the body, that gets removed once polymer has finished initializing the elements.  If you have put that attribute on the body then

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector('body[unresolved]')
```

would wait for polymer to finish loading

Another way would be to add a listener for the WebComponentsReady event to your code that sets a data-attribute on the body element when fired and then have Capybara find for the body with that attribute.

Comment: This was pretty close.  As it turns out, the wait functionality in Capybara is pretty robust.  Using the expects for some elements that I expected to be present in the DOM was really what I needed.  So although the answer you gave was 100% right, you pushed me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should listen to the `WebComponentsReady` event, it's fired when all the Polymer elements are loaded.

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready

Comment: I'm trying to leverage Capybara so I don't think you can have a Ruby method get called back when the WebComponentsReady event is fired.